# Telnet over Ethernet for Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, telnet

I have used [MikroTik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MikroTik) RouterOS and I found a telnet-over-Ethernet (a layer 2 telnet), [MAC telnet](http://www.mikrotik.com/docs/ros/2.9/tools/mactelnet.pdf) on it.

I think it's a great tool, when SSH dies, or someone misconfigures IP Addresses.
So the thing about it that you could telnet to a MAC address, log in, etc.

RouterOS is based on Linux, but are there Layer 2 telnet solutions - open-source projects (or in the repositories) under e.g.: Ubuntu, Fedora?

http://lunatic.no/2010/10/routeros-mac-telnet-application-for-linux-users/

Comment: What is “layer 2 telnet”? [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22layer+2+telnet%22) shows that you invented the term (all other occurrences have punctuation between “layer 2” and “telnet”), but you don't explain what it means.

Comment: but it exists on routeros, see PDF :P

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean. It would be better all around if you wrote clear questions without having to be prompted: you would get better answers, and other people would waste less time. That extra link could go in an answer, it's a partial answer but not really part of the question.

Comment: @gilles, it is possible to stack a tcp pdu directly on ethernet without an ip pdu; this has very limited application, but there is nothing fundamentally wrong with it.

Comment: An unstable (alpha stage) program requiring root access to run... Sounds fantastic! Oh sorry, I meant "fanatic".

Comment: Lance, admit that you just wanted to point to that single application to gain attention... And there is no useful question behind it.

Comment: I'm rather confused. You ask if *X* exists, while providing a link to *X*. Tautologically, "yes". Are you looking for other implementations (in which case, it may help also to specify what's wrong with the one you linked). Alternatively, are you looking for a *server* implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on Debian at the moment, and I see both a client (package `mactelnet-client`) and server (predictably, `mactelnet-server`). In the case of the client, `mactelnet` is the binary to run. I'd be *very* wary of the security aspect in a piece of software like this, though. Linux TCP/IP has a well-established, peer-reviewed, often audited stack and toolset.

However, as other(s) have mentioned already, if you need a remote-access console for your computer, invest in a machine with IPMI 2.0 or similar management subsystem, or buy an RS-232-to-ethernet adaptor and configure a serial `getty` on your computer. The former allows you access to the computer's BIOS/NVRAM, the latter doesn't unless your computer has ‘Serial Redirection’ support (Dell servers do, for one).

It's interesting that on non-PC servers (e.g. SPARC machines), this sort of thing is the *norm*. Our Sun T100-based boxes don't even have keyboard or display ports. All management is done via a serial or ethernet console. Older Suns automatically use the first serial port as the console unless a keyboard is plugged in on boot.

Answer (score 0):

Lance, I dont think there is much need for layer2 telnet in ubuntu and other distros when they already support serial console connections via `getty`.  Serial console clients are abundant for every major OS; however using layer2 telnet requires writing a new client, server, and protocol stack for every OS target.

Comment: i used mac-telnet very often to reach routerboards it's a very-very good thing:P

Comment: @Lance, that's fine... but most of the network / unix admins have been using serial consoles for a long time and the value added by mactelnet seems rather low to me.  It is a rare event when you can't telnet or ssh with IP; in those cases when you can't, there is a decent chance ethernet is broken too (like the device is stuck in the ROM monitor boot code).  Serial is pretty much the best option for emergency recovery.

Comment: Well, speaking as a Unix admin, I have IP KVM (so I get vga console) and also, on newer machines, IPMI (with built in IP KVM, reboot control, and serial console). All of these provide access to the BIOS as well. Layer2 telnet does not.